# Chunk a voice and do not save it in each step of processing

Tags: mfcc

I need a way that when I get voice and chunk it with librosa Library when I do this my voice change to Typeless type .
And I can not do any thing or do any progress in my voice .
Other wise I don't want to save each step of processing to have less I/O , instead I want to find a way to save the final step and keep whole steps in memory cache .
Please help me !